# How does Python 2.7 compare items inside a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I came across this interesting example today

```
class TestableEq(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.eq_run = False
    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.eq_run = True
        if isinstance(other, TestableEq):
            other.eq_run = True
        return self is other
```

---

```
>>> eq = TestableEq()
>>> eq.eq_run
False
>>> eq == eq
True
>>> eq.eq_run
True
>>> eq = TestableEq()
>>> eq is eq
True
>>> eq.eq_run
False
>>> [eq] == [eq]
True
>>> eq.eq_run    # Should be True, right?
False
>>> (eq,) == (eq,)    # Maybe with tuples?
True
>>> eq.eq_run
False
>>> {'eq': eq} == {'eq': eq}    # dicts?
True
>>> eq.eq_run
False
>>> import numpy as np    # Surely NumPy works as expected
>>> np.array([eq]) == np.array([eq])
True
>>> eq.eq_run
False
```

So it seems that comparisons inside containers works differently in Python.  I would expect that the call to `==` would use each object's implementation of `__eq__`, otherwise what's the point?  Additionally

```
class TestableEq2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.eq_run = False
    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.eq_run = True
        other.eq_run = True
        return False
```

---

```
>>> eq = TestableEq2()
>>> [eq] == [eq]
True
>>> eq.eq_run
False
>>> eq == eq
False
>>> eq.eq_run
True
```

Does this mean that Python uses `is` from within container's implementations of `__eq__` instead?  Is there a way around this?

My use case is that I am building a data structure inheriting from some of the `collections` ABCs and I want to write tests to make sure my structure is behaving correctly.  I figured it would be simple to inject a value that recorded when it was compared, but to my surprise the test failed when checking to ensure that comparison occurred.

EDIT: I should mention that this is on Python 2.7, but I see the same behavior on 3.3.

Comment: If `x is y` there is no reason to call `x == y`. I would imagine that Python is taking this shortcut. This can be verified/disprove this by creating an `eq1` *and*  an `eq2` in the tests and then using `[eq1] == [eq2]`.

Comment: @user2864740 If I wanted python to use `is`, I would have used it.  I don't want to just compare if the objects are the same, I want to know the result of `==`.  There's a big difference and I'm surprised Python seems to get it wrong.  Really it comes down to an operational difference between `[eq] == [eq]` and `[eq1] == [eq2]`.  In the first case Python will return `True` no matter what the implementation of `__eq__` is, but in the second case it will call `eq1.__eq__(eq2)`.  Why the different implementations?  Why not let me pick how elements should be compared inside a container?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you want Python to do.

Comment: @user2864740 `import this`.  The second line says "Explicit is better than implicit".  I would categorize this as implicit behavior.  I want Python to do what Python says it wants to do.

Comment: if `x is y`, then `x` should be guaranteed to equal to `y`. while, `x is y` is very easy id checking. if you indeed want `==` comparison always, you can implement yourself. it's no more than one line.

Comment: How could this ever be wrong? How could `x is y` be `True` but `x == y` is `False`.

Comment: You are not supposed to mutate classes when using `__eq__`. Also, don't take the Zen of Python so seriously. It doesn't have to apply to every single little thing. We all know there is a *lot* of implicit things going on Python.

Comment: @MJeffryes It's not necessarily about `(x is y) /= (x == y)`, it's about knowing when and how `__eq__` is being called.  When inside a container it appears that Python feels that `is` should be used for comparing elements first, then trying `__eq__` if that fails.

Comment: and, another thing involved in container comparison is, there are shortcuts in container itself. if you go `[eq, eq1] == [eq2]`, even if you can make it use `__eq__`, i can still tell they are not the same by comparing their length, therefore none of the `__eq__`'s gets called.

Comment: @bheklilr If you are asking about a behavior it is *not* about what you *want* Python to do, but rather what Python *is* doing.

Comment: When you execute operation `[eq] == [eq]` you're not evaluating the `eq` object against itself, but 2 lists with `eq` objects.

Comment: @bheklilr I think the philosophical point here is that when you run `a == b` you are explicitly calling `__eq__` on `a`. When you run `[a] == [b]` you are calling `__eq__` on the list object, which makes no guarantees about calling it on its members.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr only on reasonably defined objects. I could define `__eq__(self, other): return not self is other` if I wanted.

Comment: @AdamSmith uncommon sense yields uncommon result. if you know that is not reasonable, you should expect reasonable outcome neither.

Comment: @bheklilr: Beware invoking the Zen. No one principle trumps all others. Using identity testing as a short-circuit to equality testing is a very clear and justifiable application of *practicality beats purity*. There is no way to tell beforehand how expensive an equality test will be. But identity test is *always* cheap. Your use case (and others like it) are so vanishingly uncommon that it's not worth sacrificing the efficiency gain for the common use cases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CPython's underlying implementation will skip the equality check (`==`) for items in a list if items are identical (`is`).

CPython uses this as an optimization assuming identity implies equality.

This is documented in [PyObject_RichCompareBool](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool), which is used to compare items:

> Note: If o1 and o2 are the same object, PyObject_RichCompareBool() will always return 1 for Py_EQ and 0 for Py_NE.

From the [listobject.c](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c) implementation:

```c
/* Search for the first index where items are different */
for (i = 0; i < Py_SIZE(vl) && i < Py_SIZE(wl); i++) {
    int k = PyObject_RichCompareBool(vl->ob_item[i],
                                     wl->ob_item[i], Py_EQ);
    // k is 1 if objects are the same
    // because of RichCmopareBool's behaviour
    if (k < 0)
        return NULL;
    if (!k)
        break;
}
```

As you can see as long as `RichCompareBool` is `1` (`True`) the items are not checked.

And from [object.c](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/object.c)'s implementation of `PyObject_RichCompareBool`:

```c
/* Quick result when objects are the same.
   Guarantees that identity implies equality. */
if (v == w) {
    if (op == Py_EQ)
        return 1;
    else if (op == Py_NE)
        return 0;
}
// ... actually deep-compare objects
```

To override this you'll have to compare the items manually.

Comment: Hooray for going to the source!

Comment: I don't think it can get much more definite than this.  The documentation clearly states that I'm getting the expected behavior and that `__eq__` only gets called if the objects have different `id`s, and the source supports that claim.

Answer (score 10):

Python's testing of equality for sequences goes as follows:

```
                 Lists identical?
                  /          \  
                 Y            N
                /              \
             Equal         Same length?
                            /       \  
                           Y         N
                          /           \
                  Items identical?   Not equal
                     /       \
                    Y         N
                   /           \
                Equal      Items equal?
                            /        \
                           Y          N
                          /            \
                       Equal        Not equal
```

You can see that the equality of the items at each position is tested **only** if the two sequences are the same length but the items at each position are not identical. If you want to force equality checks to be used, you need e.g.:

```
all(item1 == item2 for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 4):

If `x is y` there is no reason to call `x == y`, by contract of `==`. Python is taking this shortcut.

This can be verified/disprove this by creating an `eq1` and an `eq2` in the tests and then using `[eq1] == [eq2]`.

[Here is as example](http://codepad.org/W9MI1IbO):

```
class TestableEq(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.eq_run = False
    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.eq_run = True
        return True     # always assume equals for test

eq1 = TestableEq()
eq2 = TestableEq()
eq3 = TestableEq()

print [eq1] == [eq2]    # True
print eq1.eq_run        # True  - implies e1 == e2 
print eq2.eq_run        # False - but NOT e2 == e1

print [eq3] == [eq3]    # True
print eq3.eq_run        # False - implies NO e3 == e3
```

When the items are `is` there is no `==` involved.

The difference with the dictionaries can be explained similarly.

Answer (score 3):

When comparing two lists, the cPython implementation short-circuits member comparisons using object equality (`obj1 is obj2`), because, according to [a comment in the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L730):

```c
/* Quick result when objects are the same.
   Guarantees that identity implies equality. */
```

If the two objects are not exactly the same object, then cPython does a rich compare, using `__eq__` if implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately Reut beat you to it so I've accepted his answer, but yours points at essentially the same evidence to show what precise behavior Python uses.