# Why is (numpy.nan, 1) == (numpy.nan, 1)?

Tags: python

While `numpy.nan` is not equal to `numpy.nan`, and `(float('nan'), 1)` is not equal to `float('nan', 1)`,

```
(numpy.nan, 1) == (numpy.nan, 1)
```

What could be the reason? 
Does Python first check to see if the ids are identical?
If identity is checked first when comparing items of a tuple, then why isn't it checked when objects are compared directly?

Comment: Please show the exact circumstances that you encounter this, because here:

`print (1, numpy.nan) == (numpy.nan, 1) => False` and `float('nan', 1)` is `TypeError`.

Comment: I would rather check with `numpy.nan is numpy.nan`

Comment: @dhke: you got your tuples reversed, which is whey they don't compare equal.

Comment: @EthanFurman: A  thanks, I thought that was the point. In that case, satoru has the proper answer below.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29692140/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/29215418/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing two objects in a tuple Python first check to see if they are the same.

Note that `numpy.nan is numpy.nan`, but `float('nan') is not float('nan')`.

In `Objects/tupleobject.c`, the comparison is carried out like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < vlen && i < wlen; i++) {
    int k = PyObject_RichCompareBool(vt->ob_item[i],
                                     wt->ob_item[i], Py_EQ);
    if (k < 0)
        return NULL;
    if (!k)
        break;
}
```

And in `PyObject_RichCompareBool`, you can see the check for equality:

```
if (v == w) {
    if (op == Py_EQ)
        return 1;
    else if (op == Py_NE)
        return 0;
}
```

You can verify this with the following example:

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print "Checking equality with __eq__"
        return True

a1 = A()
a2 = A()
```

If you try `(a1, 1) == (a1, 1)` nothing get printed, while `(a1, 1) == (a2, 1)` would use `__eq__` and print our the message.

Now try `a1 == a1` and see if it surprises you ;P

Comment: Which seems to make this a bug in `numpy.nan`, because it breaks an assumption made by the core library.

Comment: @dhke The assumption that identity implies equality is not used everywhere though. For example, `assert numpy.nan != numpy.nan`, in this case the identity check is obviously not used.

Comment: The example already established,  that `ǹumpy` does away with *identity is equality*. Python docs also explicitly state that there is not [*implied relationship*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) between `==` and `!=`, so that seems fine to me. What still bothers me where else the simple optimization in `PyObject_RichCompareBool` causes trouble. Because on the other hand `None == None` ...

Comment: I tried `a1 == a1` and got  `Checking  equality with __eq__\nTrue`.  This did not surprise me.

Comment: `float('NaN') is not float('NaN')` because two different floats were created.  `my_nan = float('NaN'); my_nan is my_nan` would be `True`.

Answer (score 6):

When you do `numpy.nan == numpy.nan` it's numpy that is deciding whether the condition is true or not. When you compare `tuples` python is just checking if the tuples have the same objects which they do. You can make `numpy` have the decision by turning the `tuples` into `numpy` arrays.

```
np.array((1, numpy.nan)) == np.array((1,numpy.nan))
>>array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

The reason is when you do `==` with `numpy` objects you're calling the numpy function `__eq__()` that says specifically that `nan != nan` because mathematically speaking `nan` is undetermined (could be anything) so it makes sense that `nan != nan`. But when you do `==` with tuples you call the tuples `__eq__()` function that doesn't care about mathematics and only cares if python objects are the same or not. In case of `(float('nan'),1)==(float('nan'),1)` it returns `False` because each call of `float('nan')` allocates memory in a different place as you can check by doing `float('nan') is float('nan')`.

Comment: Tuple compare properly calls the same `__eq__()` implementation that `==` calls, so I don't get your argument.

Comment: @dhke of course it does. I am not comparing (1,nan).__eq__((1,nan)) with (1,nan)==(1,nan). I am comparing (1,nan)==(1,nan) with np.array((1,nan))==np.array((1,nan))

Comment: Well, the OP's question is "*What could be the reason?*". Workaround is all fine, but that doesn't change the fact that `numpy.nan` breaks an assumption made by the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

Container objects are free to define what equality means for them, and for most that means one thing is really, really important:

```
for x in container:
    assert x in container
```

So containers typically do an `id` check before an `__eq__` check.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples do check first with identity and then with equality if identity doesn't match.

```
(float('nan'),) == (float('nan'),)
```

is `False` simply because a different object instance is created... if you do instead:

```
x = float('nan')
print (x,) == (x,)
```

you will get `True` too because `x == x` is False, but `x is x` is True.

Numpy `numpy.nan` is a static instance and that's why it "doesn't work".

As a wild guess this "shortcut" of checking identity first is done for performance reasons.