# Comparison of two objects with nested lists as properties

Tags: python, object, object-comparison

I have a class that looks like so:

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, a, b, c=None):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
       self.c = c  # c is presumed to be a list
   def __eq__(self, other):
       return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b
```

However, in this case "c" might be a list of Foos, with "c"s that contains list of Foos, ex something like:

```
[Foo(1,2), Foo(3,4,[Foo(5,6)])]
```

What is a good approach in dealing with this type of object comparison, given the list structure / object structure? I'm assuming that simply doing a `self.c == other.c` is insufficient for this.

Comment: Why do you think that's a problem? If you compare lists, Python will compare the elements in them to determine whether they are equal (assuming they're the same length, which is checked first). See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/29215418/3001761

Comment: Fix your `__eq__` to use `==` instead of `=` and include comparison of `c`.

Comment: `return all(getattr(self, n) == getattr(other, n) for n in ('a', 'b', 'c'))`

Comment: It also depends on how are you comparing c, if it can be a list. Do you want to take order as part of the comparison? if that's not the case you may have to convert them to sets. Maybe something like this: type(self.c) == type(other.c) and ((isinstance(self.c, list) and set(self.c) == set(other.c)) or self.c == other.c)

Comment: @Aquiles order does not matter to me actually.

Comment: Well, remember that if you are using sets for your classes you may have to add a __hash__ method as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing your `__eq__` method

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, a, b, c=None):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
       self.c = c  # c is presumed to be a list
   def __eq__(self, other):
       return self.a == other.a \
               and self.b == other.b and self.c == other.c

a,b = Foo(2,3), Foo(5,6)
c = Foo(1,2, [a,b])
d = Foo(1,2)
e,f = Foo(2,3), Foo(5,6)
g = Foo(1,2, [e,f])

print c == d #False
print c == g #True
```

Answer (score -2):

A generic solution to `n` attributes in Foo:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c  # c is presumed to be a list

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for attr, value in self.__dict__.iteritems():
            if not value == getattr(other, attr):
                return False
        return True


item1 = Foo(1, 2)
item2 = Foo(3, 4, [Foo(5, 6)])
item3 = Foo(3, 4, [Foo(5, 6)])

print(item1 == item2)  # False
print(item3 == item2)  # True
```

Comment: you may also add a type checking to avoid false positives.
`if not self.__class__ == other.__class__: return False`