# How lists are compared in python under the hood

Tags: python, algorithm

Is each element of first list being compared to one with the same index of the second list or is there another more tricky way?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes, 0 to 0, 1 to 1, etc.

Comment: there is a shortcut - if the list sizes differ, no check is needed.

Comment: Sequence typed are compared lexicographically

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga there must be some subtleties involved.  `math.nan==math.nan` returns `False` while `[math.nan]==[math.nan]` returns `True`.

Comment: @MarkRansom there are,  built in containers check identity first then equality (happens for `in` as well) as an optimization, but the comparison still works lexicographically

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You keep pointing out it's for optimization about as often as Raymond Hettinger points out it's not just for optimization :-P

Comment: @juanpa To demonstrate the "identity" part, `[float('nan')] == [float('nan')]` returns `False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Key References

The CPython3 implementation of list comparison is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8a6af5a34642f5564220eb50d72caada8f17fc78/Objects/listobject.c#L2752) on line 2752 as of the time I wrote this answer.

You can also take a look at [Python/C API Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool).

### Helper Code

I implemented a simple class that prints a message when there are calls to some of the magic methods for comparisons (e.g. `__eq__` is the method that's called when you are using the `==` operator). The class simply holds a value that you pass in the constructor. When you compare `Value` objects, their values are compared. Hopefully, this gives you a better understanding of what's going on.

```py
def show_call(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            raise NotImplementedError()
        print(f"{func.__qualname__}({', '.join(map(str, args))})")
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper


class Value:
    
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Value({self.value})"
    
    @show_call
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value
    
    @show_call
    def __lt__(self, other): 
        return self.value < other.value
    
    @show_call
    def __gt__(self, other): 
        return self.value > other.value
    
    @show_call
    def __le__(self, other): 
        return self.value <= other.value
    
    @show_call
    def __ge__(self, other): 
        return self.value >= other.value
```

### Shortcut: length differ

Let's first look at what happened when you compare the equality of two lists of different lengths. We run the following code:

```py
ls1 = [Value(1), Value(2)]

ls2 = [Value(1), Value(2), Value(3)]
print(f"{ls1} == {ls2}")
ls1 == ls2;
```

This gives the following output:

```
[Value(1), Value(2)] == [Value(1), Value(2), Value(3)]
```

We can see there's no call to the `__eq__` method. This makes sense because two lists with different lengths are considered not equal. There's no need to compare any items in the lists. In CPython, this is implemented as

> ```c
> if (Py_SIZE(vl) != Py_SIZE(wl) && (op == Py_EQ || op == Py_NE)) {
>     /* Shortcut: if the lengths differ, the lists differ */
>     if (op == Py_EQ)
>         Py_RETURN_FALSE;
>     else
>         Py_RETURN_TRUE;
> }
> ```

### The Loop

And then CPython source code says

> `Search for the first index where items are different`

We run equality tests on lists of the same length:

```py
ls3 = [Value(1), Value(2)]
print(f"{ls1} == {ls3}")
ls1 == ls3;
ls4 = [Value(2), Value(2)]
print(f"{ls1} == {ls4}")
ls1 == ls4;
```

The output is as follows:

```
[Value(1), Value(2)] == [Value(1), Value(2)]
Value.__eq__(Value(1), Value(1))
Value.__eq__(Value(2), Value(2))
[Value(1), Value(2)] == [Value(2), Value(2)]
Value.__eq__(Value(1), Value(2))
```

We can see indeed the items at index 0 are compared first, then the subsequent items. It stops when:

1. it encounters the first index where the items are not equal in the two lists; or
2. either list is exhausted.

### Final Comparisons

If either list is exhausted, we can return the comparison between the length of the two lists.

At this stage, we can already determine the equality or inequality (`!=`) for the lists, because we already found the first element that differs.

The process is all the same for less than, greater than, less than or equal to, and greater than or equal to (lt, gt, le, and ge) tests. The index of the first different item is made out. Their lengths are compared if either list is exhausted. The only difference is that it makes one last comparison with the appropriate magic method.

The following code

```py
ls5 = [Value(1), Value(3)]
print(f"{ls1} > {ls5}")
ls1 > ls5;
```

Outputs:

```
[Value(1), Value(2)] > [Value(1), Value(3)]
Value.__eq__(Value(1), Value(1))
Value.__eq__(Value(2), Value(3))
Value.__gt__(Value(2), Value(3))
```

For lt, gt, le, and ge, one last call to the appropriate comparison function is made.

### Identity Test

Also as mentioned in some of the comments, the comparisons are not a direct call to the magic methods. The identity of the two items is compared first. As you can see in the following example,

```py
ls6 = [ls1[0], Value(2)]
print(f"{ls1} == {ls6}")
ls1 == ls6;
```

outputs:

```
// ls1 ids [140401841947936, 140401277199120]
// ls6 ids [140401841947936, 140401005879200]
[Value(1), Value(2)] == [Value(1), Value(2)]
Value.__eq__(Value(2), Value(2))
```

The first item in both lists are identical (i.e. they reference the same object in C, and have the same `id` in Python). So, there's no need to call the `__eq__` function to test for equality. From the `PyObject_RichCompareBool` [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/object.c#L732) comment,

> Quick result when objects are the same. Guarantees that identity implies equality.

### Related Answer

Some of the things are already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29215682/11658924).

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

> tuples and lists are compared lexicographically by comparing corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, every element must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and have the same length. (For full details see [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) in the language reference.)